# Laravel test error "Auth driver [passport] for guard [api] is not defined" when using withoutMiddleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm trying to disable authentication middleware in my laravel api tests by using withoutMiddleware in my test case setUp method:

```
public function setUp(): void  
{
  parent::setUp();

  $this->withoutMiddleware([
    \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class
  ]);
}
```

However, when I run my tests I get the following error:

```
{
      "message": "Auth driver [passport] for guard [api] is not defined. file: \/home\/user\/.config\/composer\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Auth\/AuthManager.php line: 99",
      "errors": [] 
}
```

What is the issue?

Previously this code used to work but I think recently due to package updates this problem has occurred.